# angularjs: ignore input during form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with many input fields that are validated by AngularJS.

How can ignore one of them only from being validated ? It is only used as a commodity for the user to enter a value and add a row to a grid (which is part of the form).

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="url" >
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="addUrl();">+</button>
```

In the above code, the user enters some text in the input and click the + button. The problem is that the input is validated by AngularJS when the form is submitted, which is not what I want.

I've tried adding ng-non-bindable to the input. That works but then I can't bind the 'url' property obviously....

What's the workaround for this ?

Comment: input has no `name`, shouldn't get validated since it is not able to be submitted

Comment: Maybe it's not validated, but the form becomes dirty though.

Comment: You can reset the `$dirty` property of a form after the user clicks the button and `addUrl()` is called.  See `$setPristine`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form.FormController

Comment: alternately, could move input out of form and position it on top of form, depending on layout constraints

Comment: @m.e.conroy I can't do that because the form might have been dirty from some other modifications.

Comment: @charlietfl the layout of the form is too complex for me to move the input out.

Comment: have never used it...but can nest forms in angular for validation purposes, might be what you need

Comment: yes forms can be nested with angular, but that means that if the child form becomes dirty, then the parent form will become dirty too. This is not what I want. In my case, the input textbox should have no impact whatsoever (dirty and validation) on the actual form.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the form controller in the directives linking function, and remove the input from validation like this:

```
app.directive('customInput', function(){
  return {
    template: '<input>',
    restrict : 'E',
    require : '^form',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {
      var inputCtrl = elem.controller('ngModel');
      formCtrl.$removeControl(inputCtrl);
    }
  }
})
```

I've setup a plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AR0Zk1ybQ7OvmHEGirVL?p=preview

Comment: When you replace the custom-input with <input>, there's no model on it anymore, and that's why the form doesn't show as dirty. The plunker works the same even without the link function. And if you add a ng-model="field2" in the template, it doesn't work. Is there a way to get access to the input's value via angular without having the field affect the form's pristine state?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I see my mistake.
One further precondition must be set to use $removeControl: The input element must have a name.
The function is defined as:
  form.$removeControl = function(control) {
    if (control.$name && form[control.$name] === control) {
      delete form[control.$name];
    }
    forEach(errors, function(queue, validationToken) {
      form.$setValidity(validationToken, true, control);
    });

    arrayRemove(controls, control);
  };

But unfortunatly though delete is executed then, it does not what I would expect.